# Problem building a generic inherited class in C#

Tags: c#, generics, abstraction

I wrote the following classes and I don't know why the line:

```
return new PersonEncrypterDecrypter()
```

which is in the class `EncrypterDecrypterBuilder<T>` does not work.

It is said that that casting is not allowed but I do not see any reason that it should be a problem.

Here is a link to the code :

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f10c6bb11a3c79d

Edit: did some changes (the link to the code is updated).

I wrote a `main` method like this:

```
EncrypterDecrypter<Entity>e1 = 
EncrypterDecrypterBuilder<Entity>.Builder(eEncryptersDecrypters.Person);
 Dictionary<string, string> dic = e1.DataDecrypter(test);
```

and I get an `System.InvalidCastException` when trying to execute the first line:

```
return (EncrypterDecrypter<T>)(new PersonEncrypterDecrypter())
```

which is in the class `EncrypterDecrypterBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue is with `static class EncrypterDecrypterBuilder` method. Static constructor
couldn't have a parameter and can't return a value. Looks like you just want to have a static method. Rename this method. Also, you will need to cast the object in return clause

```
public static class EncrypterDecrypterBuilder<T> where T : Entity
{
    public static EncrypterDecrypter<T> EncrypterDecrypterBuilderSomeNewName()
    {

        return (EncrypterDecrypter<T>)(new PersonEncrypterDecrypter());
    }
}
```

See all code:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a3d3fef3b7af7f2

Comment: i wrote the following line in the main after i did the change( the name and the casting) : EncrypterDecrypter<Entity> e1 = EncrypterDecrypterBuilder<Entity>.Builder(eEncryptersDecrypters.Person);   but during run time i get an invalid casting exception

Comment: T is Entity. You can't cast EncrypterDecrypter<Person> to EncrypterDecrypter<Entity>. Use public interface EncrypterDecrypter<out T> where T : Entity

Comment: You want to cover a lot of stuff in this topic(and not related to your first issue). Start with this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Comment: I did what you  suggested but i got the following error : https://imgur.com/8EexTtj

Comment: Please start with understanding what is Covariance and Contravariance. Use link above.

Comment: Thanks alot it works, I will read the article you gave in order to understand.